# Function treats string as single value instead of parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a tags plugin that takes input like this just fine:

```
$(this).tagHandler({
   assignedTags: [ 'test','from','reddit' ]
});
```

If however I create a variable named tags that is a string:

```
tags = "'test','from','reddit'";
```

And attempt to use it in the function it gets treated as a single string.

```
$(this).tagHandler({
   assignedTags: [ tags ]
});
```

Instead of being processed through the function I end up with 'test','from','reddit' as a single tag.

I have a feeling this is a common problem but haven't found the right search phrase to identify the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. You were all correct that I needed to pass an array instead of trying to pass a string that looked like one! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply an array - the string you've created won't automatically get converted into one:

```
var tags = ['test', 'from', 'reddit'];
$(this).tagHandler({
   assignedTags: tags
});
```

If all you have is a string, try:

```
var str = 'test,from,reddit';
var tags = str.split(',');
$(this).tagHandler({
   assignedTags: tags
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array may work.

```
tags = new Array('test','from','reddit');
$(this).tagHandler({
   assignedTags: tags
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because this is

```
 [ 'test','from','reddit' ]
```

is an array

and what you have does in put a sting into an array you should

what you want is to make an array

```
 var tags = ['test','from','reddit'];
```

then add it

```
$(this).tagHandler({
    assignedTags: tags 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you expect the string to be parsed, does the plugin indicate it will do that? My guess is the following might work:

```
$(this).tagHandler({
   assignedTags: [ tags.split(',') ]
});`
```